# After adding social Authentication, the classic login form authentication doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-oauth, php-7.4, symfony5.4

Last night, I implemented a social authentication with Google in my project. I used the [knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle).
It worked fine till I tried to login with the classic form.

After submitting login form (with correct email and password), I'm redirected to /login and no error is displayed.
I tried to dump $request to check  to check what I get from the form = I never enter into the authenticate() method, that means I do not enter into the UserAuthenticator which handles the authentication.
So I think my main issue is in the security.yaml. As I have 2 custom_authenticators, I need to set the entry point (which is UserAuthenticator). I followed the Symfony 5.4 documentation to set it up properly, but I'm missing something because it still doesn't log the user in.
On the other hand, Google Authenticator works very well...
And my registration form has no problem.

The main problem is therefore between the UserAuthenticator, LoginController and security.yaml files.

Here you have the UserAuthenticator.php file :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('default'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

here the LoginController.php file :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {  
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    
        if ($error) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'danger',
                'Attention ! L\'email ou le mot de passe sont erronés.'
            );
        }   
        
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }

    
}
```

here the security.yaml file :

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            entry_point: App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            custom_authenticators: 
                - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true


    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: (?!/(login|register|reset-password)), roles: ROLE_USER}
        - { path: ^/back, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy: 
        # ROLE_ADMIN included ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

and here the GoogleAuthenticator.php file :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GoogleUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class GoogleAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator
{
    private $clientRegistry;
    private $em;
    private $router;
    
    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $em, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_google_check';
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('google');
        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function() use ($accessToken, $client) {
                /** @var GoogleUser $googleUser */
                $googleUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);

                $email = $googleUser->getEmail();

                // 1) have they logged in with Google before? Easy!
                $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $googleUser->getId()]);

                if ($existingUser) {
                    return $existingUser;
                }

                // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
                $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

                $user->setFirstName($googleUser->getFirstName());
                $user->setLastName($googleUser->getLastName());
                $user->setUserName($googleUser->getName());
                $user->setEmail($googleUser->getEmail());
                $user->setPassword('$2y$13$Qd.wjexSJuPUhqqYAGxo/eg6W66cglojs/wg2VsnU.00Ax9OtEcbC');
                $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
                $this->em->persist($user);
                $this->em->flush();

                return $user;
            })
        );
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/login', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication failed
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication was successfull
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $firewallName
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('default');

        return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);

    }

}
```

I tried to set the security.yaml file like this (with form_login) but it doesn't read the UserAuthenticator and uses deprecated functions since Symfony 5.3 :

```yaml
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            form_login: 
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticators: 
                - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

I searched all documentation about setting these files, but it seems to be tricky !

If you have any idea, I'll be really grateful